# What Are The Necessary Conditions For a Function to be Separable?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

A common step in solving many PDEs is to write a multivariable solution function as a product of two more or single variable  functions.  For example, if given,

$$
\alpha\,\frac{\partial U(x,t)}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial U(x,t)}{\partial t},
$$

one may begin be writing,

$$
U(x,t) = X(x) T(t).
$$

My question is, what are the necessary conditions for writing a multi variable function as a product of  several single variable functions?  Furthermore, are there any cases where this cannot be done?

Comment: Pretty sure you could say that if your pde looks like this (just taking two independent variables - the generalization would work as well): $$f_1(x,U,U_x,U_{xx},\cdots)+f_2(x,U,U_x,U_{xx},\cdots)+\cdots+f_n(x,U,U_x,U_{xx},\cdots)+g_1(y,U,U_y,U_{yy},\cdots)+g_2(y,U,U_y,U_{yy},\cdots) +\cdots+g_m(y,U,U_y,U_{yy},\cdots)=0,$$ those would be sufficient conditions. I'm less sure about necessary conditions. You might also need the pde to be linear.

Comment: There are certainly loads of non-separable pde's out there.

Answer (score 2):

Of course most two-variable functions $U(x,t)$ cannot be written as $X(x) T(t)$. Those that can are, well, those that happen to be of that form...

The point in the context of PDEs like the heat equation is that you want to find a whole **sequence** of such separable solutions $U_n(x,t)=X_n(x) T_n(t)$ that you can use in order to write the general solution as a **linear combination** of these simple solutions: $U(x,t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n U_n(x,t)$.

Comment: Yes, but it is important to note that the linearity of the differential operators are important for this to work.

Comment: @mathreadler: Certainly!

Answer (score 1):

A sufficient and necessary condition is the following.

A function $F:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}:(x,y)\mapsto F(x,y)$ can be written as $F(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$ for some functions $f,g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ **if and only if** for every $x,y,w,z\in\mathbb{R}$ it holds that
$$F(x,y)F(z,w)=F(x,w)F(z,y).$$

The implication "$\implies$" follows directly from the commutativity of multiplication and the other implication is obtained by first noticing that the zero function $F=0$ can obviously be written as a product of functions of a single variable, and if there exists some $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $F(a,b)\neq 0$, then we get that $\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ it holds
$$F(x,y)F(a,b)=F(x,b)F(a,y),$$ which implies that

$$F(x,y)=F(x,b)\frac{F(a,y)}{F(a,b)}=f(x)g(y).$$